# scanf function doesn't scan properly

Tags: c, string

this is the code:

```
StudentTree* readStudentFile(FILE* studentFile){
StudentTree *node=NULL;
StudentTree *tree=NULL;
int id;
char name[10]="\0";
char lastname[10]="\0";
int number;
int grade;

fscanf(studentFile,"%9d%10c%10c%4d%*c%3d",&id,name,lastname,&number,&grade);
```

and somehow the variable name gets all the 20 chars, and the variable lastname
gets only the second 10 chars.
I want that the variable name will get only the first 10 chars.

Comment: Show an instance of the file.

Comment: Unless you're doing something particularly unusual, you shouldn't ever need to put `\0` in a string literal as they're implicitly null-terminated. `char s[] = "";` is the same as `char s[] = {'\0'};`.

Answer (score 2):

The character arrays must be defined as

```
char name[11] = "\0";
char lastname[11] = "\0";
```

to have enough space for 10 characters plus a terminating NUL-character.

What happens in your case is probably that `lastname` immediately follows `name`
in the memory, so that printing `name` prints the characters of *both* arrays
(and perhaps more, until a NUL-character is found).

Answer (score 0):

the explanation is rather simple.

First: The variables "name" and "lastname" are probably allocated by the compiler in adjacent positions.

Second: the %c directive for scanf does not put a null terminator when it "moves" the characters in your char buffer.

In other words, the "string" "name" finds as first null terminator the null terminator of the string lastname.

Try the %s directive which puts the null terminator differently than the %c command. It should do the trick.

Cheers
Maurizio

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

1. It's wrong to use the conversion specifier `%9d` in the format string of `scanf`. It doesn't mean that `fscanf` will read an integer having at most `9` digits. Maximum filed width can only be used with `%s` or with the conversion specifier beginning with `%[..]`.
2. You can use the `%s` conversion specifier and `fscanf` will automatically put a terminating null byte at the end to mark the end of the string.
3. If the purpose of `%*c` is to skip a whitespace character, then you don't need it here because `%d` anyway skips all the leading whitespace characters.
4. You should check the return value of `fscanf` to know if there were failure in input matching and assignment. `fscanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.

I suggest the following -

```
// +1 for the terminating null byte
// added by fscanf. This assumes that
// name and lastname are no longer than
// 10 characters in length.
char name[10+1], lastname[10+1];
int id;
int number;
int grade;

// %10s means that fscanf will read at most 10 chars
// or till it encounters a whitespace - whichever occurrs
// first and then add a null byte at the end
int retval = fscanf(studentFile, "%d%10s%10s%d%d", 
                    &id, name, lastname, &number, &grade);

if(retval != 5) {
    // assignment failure due to 
    // bad format in the input
}
```

However, it's always better to use `fgets` to read lines from a file and then use `sscanf` to parse the line because if `fgets` fails to match and assign an input item, then the file pointer will be left in an unknown location.